# What's the official term for the part(s) of instrument(s) playing the exact same score?

Tags: terminology

'Part' refers to instrument(s) (families) that play(s) the exact same bars and have the exact same score, e.g. what is played by the second violins in [*Fresco*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresco_(Stockhausen)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is kind of unclear without the actual score, but it sound like it is just a *part doubling*. When multiple instruments (or instrument groups) play the same thing at the same time the part is considered doubled. Think of it as everyone singing the same melody at the same time and it gives the peice a certain texture.